# Web-scraping articles from WSJ using Beautifulsoup in python 3.7?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape articles from the Wall Street Journal using Beautifulsoup in Python. However, the code which I am running is executing without any error (exit code 0) but no results. I don't understand what is happening? Why this code is not giving expected results.

I even have paid a subscription.

I know that something is not right but I can't locate the problem.

```
import time

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.wsj.com/search/term.html?KEYWORDS=cybersecurity&min-date=2018/04/01&max-date=2019/03/31' \
  '&isAdvanced=true&daysback=90d&andor=AND&sort=date-desc&source=wsjarticle,wsjpro&page={}'

pages = 32
for page in range(1, pages+1):
    res = requests.get(url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".items.hedSumm li > a"):
        resp = requests.get(item.get("href"))
        _href = item.get("href")

        try:
            resp = requests.get(_href)
        except Exception as e:
            try:
            resp = requests.get("https://www.wsj.com" + _href)
        except Exception as e:
            continue
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
    date = sauce.select("time.timestamp.article__timestamp.flexbox__flex--1")
    date = date[0].text
    tag = sauce.select("li.article-breadCrumb span").text
    title = sauce.select_one("h1.wsj-article-headline").text
    content = [elem.text for elem in sauce.select("p.article-content")]
    print(f'{date}\n {tag}\n {title}\n {content}\n')

    time.sleep(3)
```

As I wrote in the code, I am trying to scrape date, title, tag, and content of all the articles. It would be helpful if I can get suggestions about my mistakes, what should I do to get the desired results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace your code :

```
resp = requests.get(item.get("href"))
```

To:

```
_href = item.get("href")

try:
    resp = requests.get(_href)
except Exception as e:
    try:
        resp = requests.get("https://www.wsj.com"+_href)
    except Exception as e:
        continue
```

Because most of `item.get("href")` is not providing proper website url for eg you are getting url like this.

```
/news/types/national-security
/public/page/news-financial-markets-stock.html
https://www.wsj.com/news/world
```

Only `https://www.wsj.com/news/world` is a valid website URL. so you need to concate `base URL` with `_href`.

**Update**:

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag

url = 'https://www.wsj.com/search/term.html?KEYWORDS=cybersecurity&min-date=2018/04/01&max-date=2019/03/31' \
  '&isAdvanced=true&daysback=90d&andor=AND&sort=date-desc&source=wsjarticle,wsjpro&page={}'

pages = 32

for page in range(1, pages+1):
    res = requests.get(url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

    for item in soup.find_all("a",{"class":"headline-image"},href=True):
        _href = item.get("href")
        try:
            resp = requests.get(_href)
        except Exception as e:
            try:
                resp = requests.get("https://www.wsj.com"+_href)
            except Exception as e:
                continue

        sauce = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
        dateTag = sauce.find("time",{"class":"timestamp article__timestamp flexbox__flex--1"})
        tag = sauce.find("li",{"class":"article-breadCrumb"})
        titleTag = sauce.find("h1",{"class":"wsj-article-headline"})
        contentTag = sauce.find("div",{"class":"wsj-snippet-body"})

        date = None
        tagName = None
        title = None
        content = None

        if isinstance(dateTag,Tag):
            date = dateTag.get_text().strip()

        if isinstance(tag,Tag):
            tagName = tag.get_text().strip()

        if isinstance(titleTag,Tag):
            title = titleTag.get_text().strip()

        if isinstance(contentTag,Tag):
            content = contentTag.get_text().strip()

        print(f'{date}\n {tagName}\n {title}\n {content}\n')
        time.sleep(3)
```

O/P:

```
March 31, 2019 10:00 a.m. ET
 Tech
 Care.com Removes Tens of Thousands of Unverified Listings
 The online child-care marketplace Care.com scrubbed its site of tens of thousands of unverified day-care center listings just before a Wall Street Journal investigation published March 8, an analysis shows. Care.com, the largest site in the U.S. for finding caregivers, removed about 72% of day-care centers, or about 46,594 businesses, listed on its site, a Journal review of the website shows. Those businesses were listed on the site as recently as March 1....

Updated March 29, 2019 6:08 p.m. ET
 Politics
 FBI, Retooling Once Again, Sets Sights on Expanding Cyber Threats
 The FBI has launched its biggest transformation since the 2001 terror attacks to retrain and refocus special agents to combat cyber criminals, whose threats to lives, property and critical infrastructure have outstripped U.S. efforts to thwart them. The push comes as federal investigators grapple with an expanding range of cyber attacks sponsored by foreign adversaries against businesses or national interests, including Russian election interference and Chinese cyber thefts from American companies, senior bureau executives...
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but no results. Again showing exit code 0 but nothing. I have updated code in my question to show if I have made any mistake or not.

Comment: I copy pasted your code and tried it but no results. Exit code 0. Nothing is printed. What can be the problem? As I can see it is running fine in your system. Why it is not working for me? Can you explain what is leading to this problem?

Comment: @Piyush Ghasiya I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and it's working perfectly.  I don't know why is not working on your system.

Comment: @Piyush Ghasiya You should create a new workspace and try my updated code.

Comment: @PiyushGhasiya, bharatk's code work fine for me as well (on windows).

Comment: @bharatk I am working on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and code produces no output for me. I also created new environment as you suggested in your comment but it didn`t help. Is this code  deprecated or I am having same issue as other people in the comments?